# How to select/update only same GUID from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid

In SQL Server I am trying to update specific column of a table when its GUID and another's are the same.

```
 UPDATE [A].[Sch].[Box]
     SET [FFType_Id] = 5
 WHERE [A].[Sch].[Box].Id = (SELECT id from [B].Sch.Boxes)
```

I understand that GUID can't be compared and that's why I tried to `CAST()` or `CONVERT()`

```
N''''+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),[B].Sch.Boxes.Id)+  N''''
```

and

```
CAST([B].Sch.Boxes.Id AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

In addition when i query

```
SELECT [A].Sch.Box.Id, [B].Sch.Boxes.Id 
FROM [A].Sch.Box INNER JOIN [B].Sch.Boxes 
                         ON [A].Sch.Box.Id = [B].Sch.Boxes.Id
                         WHERE [A].Sch.Box.Id= [B].Sch.Boxes.Id
```

it returns all ids (Same or note) but when i query

```
SELECT [A].Sch.Box.Id, [B].Sch.Boxes.Id 
FROM [A].Sch.Box INNER JOIN [B].Sch.Boxes 
                         ON [A].Sch.Box.Id = [B].Sch.Boxes.Id
                         WHERE [A].Sch.Box.Id= '0DB2F38E-DE98-43B9-9333-8CD395506858'
```

It returns only that one

Comment: "*In SQL server i am trying to update specific column of a table when its GUID and another's are the same.*" Sorry, but this is underspecified. What *exactly* do you mean by that? Please add example data to your question and specify which rows should be updated by your SQL and which shouldn't.

Comment: "I understand that GUID can't be compared" - what on earth does this mean? Of course GUIDs can be compared?

Comment: @DaleK In SQL server? 
How? 
table.column1 = table.column2  doesn't filter it at all

Comment: In that case you have some other issue, because comparing 2 guids as you say does work. You need to provide a [mre] (e.g. a DBFiddle) to show us what specifically is going wrong for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server every data except for some operators can be compared. `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` can be compared...

Your query can be solved by:

```
UPDATE T1
SET    [FFType_Id] = 5
FROM   [A].[Sch].[Box] AS T1
       JOIN [B].Sch.Boxes AS T2 
          ON T1.Id = T2.Id;
```

With a join between the two GUIDs.